# Userscript to show Winterbash hats on meta sites?

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange

[Winterbash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com) is happening!

But there is a conspicuous lack of hats on per-site metas. I'd like to see people wearing their hats when viewing a meta post.

To that end, I would like to have a userscript that enables hats on Meta. Requirements:

- Show hats everywhere that they are shown on the main site, including user profiles and posts
- It should show the hat that the user is wearing on the main site.
- It doesn't need the ability to *change* the hat from the meta site.
- It must work on the latest version of Chrome running on OS X Yosemite.

Is there a script that does this?

Comment: The start of an answer can be found at: [How save profile photo with winter bash hat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245205/1438). [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) would be a good place to check as well. (Nothing appropriate exists there at the moment, however.)

Comment: Don't spend too much time on this -- I've asked internally yesterday if anyone remembers the reason why we don't show hats on child metas, and so far I haven't received any answers (I certainly don't remember it). Unless there is a good reason after all that someone recalls, I'll enable hats on metas soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hats are now enabled on child metas, see [No hats on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280387/115866). Thus to answer your software recommendation question: I recommend [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

The nice thing about Vanilla JS is that it's really great at doing nothing; in fact that's all it does. I've been using it a lot (you'll notice that we – Stack Overflow – are actually listed in the "who's using it" section), and whenever I didn't need anything, Vanilla JS was able to perfectly provide all I needed.

And since you're exactly in the same position – you don't need anything, because hats already are on metas – I'm very sure that Vanilla JS will work great for you as well.